# How to get all items in the list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to get all items in the list, but my script shows only the first item. Please refer to the verifyDisplay assertion in for loop, where I want to show all items in the list. Thanks for the help.

My script:

```
List<WebElement> groups = driver.findElements(By
            .xpath(".//*[@id='competitiveCategoryTemp']/option"));

    verifyDisplay("'" + competitive_categories_id_with_space + "'" + "===> The newly added Competitive Category is listed",
            By.xpath(".//*[@id='competitiveCategoryTemp']/option"));


    boolean sortedGroups = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < groups.size() - 1; i++) {

        verifyDisplay("'" + groups.get(i).getText() + "'" + "\n"+ 
                "Other Competitive Categories are available and names are SORTED",
                By.xpath(".//*[@id='competitiveCategoryTemp']/option"));

        if (groups.get(i).getText()
                .compareToIgnoreCase(groups.get(i + 1).getText()) > 0) {
            sortedGroups = true;
            break;

        }
        sortedGroups = true;
    }

    if (sortedGroups) {
        System.out.println("The Competitive Category names are SORTED");

    } else
        System.out.println("The Competitive Category names are UN-SORTED");

}
```

Comment: Did you setup breakpoints and use the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (groups.get(i).getText()
            .compareToIgnoreCase(groups.get(i + 1).getText()) > 0) {
        sortedGroups = true;
        break;
}
```

If this condition is met, it breaks out of the for loop, and thus does not proceed forward to the second element. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver has **Select** class to control dropdown objects. Your approach will also work. But this way it will look neat and you can reuse the existing methods.

Import this lib.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
```

Then,

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("competitiveCategoryTemp")));

dropdown.getOptions()  // will return all the options - it is a List<WebElement>

//To use
for(WebElement option: dropdown.getOptions()){
   System.out.println(option.getText());
}

dropdown.getAllSelectedOptions() // will return the default selected options - it is a List<WebElement>
```

Comment: it shows this in the output, if dropdown.getOptioins()...........      [[[[FirefoxWebDriver: firefox on MAC (d382c52b-a4b5-ea4c-bb54-969268dd4031)] -> xpath: .//*[@id='competitiveCategoryTemp']]]